# Creating planes when remeshing/Topology

Tags: vertices, faces, tools

As a newbie I'm following a tutorial that makes really fast work of creating planes when remeshing on top of a UV, but I cant figure out for the life of me how to create planes like in the video.

The person draws a few vertices dots in empty space like with a knife tool and then there's a plane. Ive tried watching many other videos but still cant figure it out.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ye7AlE7VGQg
Its clear at around minute 1.12 at 0.25x speed

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like he's using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> which is the *Extrude to Cursor* operation (it creates an edge between the selected vertex and the location of the cursor):

[image]

Then he creates the opposite edge loop, he fills the first edge with <kbd>F</kbd>, then he just needs to press <kbd>F</kbd> again and as much as needed to fill the next faces:

[image]

Comment: Tysm moonboots!!! Ive been trying to figure this out for so long!